# Using Data Source Configuration Wizard from Source View?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm developing an asp.net site over a pretty slow network. The "Design" view of the remote Visual Studio doesn't work via Remote Desktop Connection-- and this is the only way I've seen in the docs to open the Data Source Config. Wizard.

Is there a way to invoke the Data Source Config. Wizard from the source view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is only available in the design view. What you might want to do, if you aren't familiar with the code that it generates is, set one up in a test environment, on your current machine and then you can write out the code over the network.